# How to detect 403 Errors on images in one place?

Tags: javascript

This error is thrown when my site is used inside an organization that blocks certain domains - i.e. social sites etc.  They are just links to images on these domains using `<img src = "">`

**From Chrome Console**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
>   (Forbidden: category denied)
>   "Followed by URL"

How can I detect this error pragmatically and have a default image display instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this:

```
 function imgError(image){
        image.onerror = "";
        image.src = "/images/noimage.gif";
        return true;
    }

    <img src="someimage.png" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```

Comment: easier to just capture these at the window during the capture phase with a single event handler.

Comment: It doesn't seems to be working for the image url that returns 403

Answer (score 2):

If you use jquery you can do:

```
$("img").error(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", "default-image.png");
  });
```

Comment: because if you detect at windows you catch also errors for iframe, scripts, css,...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onerror` attribute to execute JavaScript function to change the `src` attribute.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onerror.asp