# javascript: how to detect http 4XX errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

Our website runs a lot of javascripts, I want to capture those client side errors, including javascript errors together with http errors (403 forbidden, 404 not found), and send them back to server via ajax call.

Right now I am able to capture javascript errors with `window.onerror` function, but for those 403 404 http errors I have no clue, [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503943/how-to-detect-403-errors-on-images-in-one-place) is very helpful if the missing resource has `img` tag, and I am able to record it,  but is there any more general way to detect 403/404 errors, not just for 'img' tag?

PS: I know that chrome console shows all http errors, but I want to detect it using javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just do something on the server-side? That seems a lot easier to me...

Comment: Do you mean errors when you make an AJAX request in JS, or errors actually downloading a .js file included in the page by a `<script>` tag?

Comment: we are loading a lot of images and videos from third party. those http errors can only happen in client side.

Comment: @JasonLi Unless you proxy them through your server, though that of course has it's own problems.

Comment: If you're interested in catching Ajax 4XX responses, the [`$(document).ajaxError`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) handler may be of interest to you. (`jqXHR.status` has the status code in the callback.) This will not help you capture `<img>` errors, of course.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, errors when making ajax calls should already be handled in the ajax calls. if they throw errors I need to capture them

Comment: I am wondering, how Chrome shows those http errors in console. Is there any way to capture the errors chrome detects?

Comment: @apsillers, thanks but I am interested in capturing http errors in javascript